# 404 cehck status for current page

Tags: wordpress

**i want to check current page's 404 status in a plugin file**
*i tried this but page only spinning and never finish loading*

```
public static function check_404_status($my_url)
{
      $result = false;
      $my_url = self::tc_trim_slash($my_url);
      $ch = curl_init($my_url); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
      curl_exec($ch); 
      $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
      if($retcode != 200) { 
           $result=true;
           return $result;
      } 
      else { 
        // echo "Specified URL exists"; 
      }    
      curl_close($ch);            
}
```

**i have also tried this but it gives error**
*is_404 was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.)*

```
  public static function check_404_status($my_url)
{
      $result = false;
      $my_url = self::tc_trim_slash($my_url);
      if(is_404())
     {
      $result=true;
      return $result;
     }
}
```

I am new to wordpress, can someone please help me to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

`is_404()` conditional is set in the WP_Query class and checks is the query returns a 404 (returns no results)

So, you can try to modify your function like that

```
public static function check_404_status()
{
  global $wp_query;
  if (isset($wp_query)) {
    return $wp_query->is_404();
  }
  return false;
}
```